# How can I set the precision of a BigDecimal-typed property in a Java record?

Tags: java

As the title of this question suggests, I want to be able to set a precision for a BigDecimal-typed record property. During my work, I was writing some code to deserialise files from an FTP server and encountered this problem.

```java
record WorldRecordDto(
    // Price can have any precision, even if undesired
    // e.g. (0.000004, 2,50, 12412414,1000100410)
    BigDecimal price
) {}
```

Traditional Java classes are something that I want to avoid, since they are mutable (DTOs should be immutable IMO) and too long for what they do. I'm aware of the fact that you can fix the BigDecimal precision in a setter, but this approach does not really apply to records. Sure, you can override the constructor, but is there a more elegant way of doing this? Also, this solution is painful if you are writing big DTOs.

I have searched for solutions with annotations, but I could not find anything useful.

Comment: Looks to me like this is a problem for the client of that DTO, not for the DTO itself. By the way, if you want non-standard behavior you'll probably have to bend over and use a custom constructor. Or set the precision of the value before creating the record.

Comment: So you want `WorldRecordDto` to set the precision of the big decimal that are passed into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oof. A few topics to cover here.

### Miscellaneous

it's `Dto`, not `DTO`. For the same reason it's `DvdPlayer`, not `DVDPlayer`, in java - acronyms, even if customarily written in all-caps, are *not* written in all caps when CamelCasing the name.

### BD precision

records are containers to store references and values. It's not about the value *itself*. Hence, what you want can't be done, but, you can make a new BD during construction:

```
record BridgeDto(BigDecimal span) {
  public BridgeDto {
    span = span.setScale(2);
  }
}
```

This will increase or decrease the scale of the input to 2 and *returns a new BigDecimal* (so, generally, `BridgeDto b = new BridgeDto(x); System.out.println(b.span() == x);` will print `false`!)

If the provided value cannot be scaled down to 2 (e.g. because it is 14.955), that will cause an exception which, presumably, you want to happen. There are alternatives available (`.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR)`, for example), but using BigDecimal for a price and then introducing silent rounding is, in a word, idiotic.

### That's not how you price

There are only 3 significant ways to represent money:

1. Adhere to atomicity
2. Allow sub-atomicity
3. Go all out and have one value that represents the lot, *including* what kind of currency it is.

An 'atomic' is that unit of currency such that '1' of such currency is the very minimal amount that banking systems for that currency can represent.

For euros, dollars, and many other currencies, the atomic is 'cent'. For pounds, it is pennies. For japanese Yen it's.. Yen. For Bitcoin, it's satoshis. Every currency has an atomic.

### I want sub-atomics

I really really doubt that.

And here's the thing: If you *do not* wants sub-atomics, then **you do not want `BigDecimal`**.

Imagine the following idea:

You are a bank. You allow the creation of shared joint accounts, where the account's owners are always own an equal share of the account. Alex, Brent, and Caroline create a joint account.

Eventually, €1.04 is in the joint account.

At that point, the 3 owners jointly decide to cancel the joint account.

Your bank has a primitive operation to do this: "`jointAccount.cancel()`". It is implemented as you'd expect: The accountnumber is freed or at least marked as inactive, and *the funds are transferred to the joint holders*.

So far, so obvious right? This shouldn't come across as a contrived example.

The thing is, **how**? 1.04 is not divisible by 3. Not even if you introduce sub-atomics!

A few wrong answers:

- We divide 1.04 by 3, using BigDecimal math. This causes an exception because you can't do that (try it!), so, the bank's documentation is updated to list that cancelling a joint account is not possible unless the amount in it is exactly divisible by the number of joint holders it has.
- We divide 1.04 by 3 using BigDecimal math that has a set rounding mode. This causes 1 cent to appear or disappear, who knows. Some enterprising soul figures out a way to repeatedly make a joint account with 100 holders, transfer 76 cents into it, cancel it, and watch the bank transfer 1 whole cents to each holder, earning 24 cents every time you do this. The bank figures this out, and updates the code to always round down. At which point someone figures to open a joint account with 100 holders, let it go to -99 cents, cancel it, and watch how 0 cents are debited from each joint holder because it now rounds down. The bank notices again and fires the dev team that decided to mess with sub-atomics in the first place.

The right answer:

- The code that powers 'cancel joint account' fundamentally understands that 'divide up the cash' is not something that can be generalized to a mathematical model, and is instead something that needs to be custom designed anytime 'divvy up some cash' comes up in any system. The code for `jointAccount.cancel()` will actually distribute the funds/debts equally as far as 'fits', will then take the remainder, and distribute that randomly (as in, random number generators) amongst the account holders. In other words, if Alex, Brent, and Caroline cancel their €1.04 account, randomly two of them get 35 cents and one of them gets 34. Alternatively, the bank defines in their terms of service that such cases are rounded in the bank's favour: They all get 34 cents (but, had it been a balance of -€1.04, they'd all lose 35 cents!)

### So why not BD?

Because it just misleads. BD's primary purpose is to let you represent sub-atomics. If you consider 'anytime any algorithm dips into sub-atomics, that's actually wrong', then why use it? It just taunts you (and therefore, misleads anybody reading your code, after all, if you use 'feature X that is primarily known to do Y', one makes the assumption that Y is important, you need *a lot* of commenting to explain that Y is to be avoided!

### The alternative - no sub-atomics

Instead represent your money values in `long`. And they represent **atomics**, not the standard currency. In other words, the account balance of Alex, Brent, and Caroline's joint account is `long v = 104;`.

### But.. that wouldn't format properly!

But BD doesn't solve that problem. Anytime any monetary amount is to be shown to the user, it needs to be passed to a formatter than can do this. `String.format("€%d.%02d", v / 100, Math.abs(v % 100))` does the job.

### That feels too low level

Then separate 'how to store it in the DB' from 'how it is represented in java' and use e.g. [Joda-money](https://www.joda.org/joda-money/).

### What about forex?

Foreign exchange rates are often a really long decimal number. For such operations, take your value (in `long`), convert it to a BD, multiply it by the forex rate (also a BD), take the result, round it according to the code (generally, in the bank's favour which is rounding up or down depending on what's happening and the sign of the value, so, you need a bunch of `if` statements to do this correctly), and then you're back to a `long` which you can store, send to other methods, make API calls with, store in the DB, and so forth.

Sticking with BD is no solution (given that you'd need to round the end result or figure out a way to store/transfer sub-atomics, and if you're going to go through all that trouble, just use `long`).

### Immutable dtos

That's.. wrong. DTO objects represent 'row in the database', and rows are generally mutable. Classes should accurately model the thing they represent. If the thing they represent is locked to a principle you cannot change (and 'row in DB', well, unless you invent your own db engine, you're somewhat limited in how far you can stretch what that means at a semantic level), then you need to model it as accurately as you can, and that includes mutability if the underlying concept is mutable. "Prefer immutability" refers to the notion that usually you are in control of what a thing means, so architect your applications to be designed around immutables.

As an example, git (the version control system) treats all commits as immutable and is architected accordingly. The one and only thing in the git architectural design that is mutable, is a branch name. Hence, 'amend a commit' is translated to 'make an entirely new commit, given that amending is impossible as commits are immutable, then update the `main` branch ref to this newly created commit'.

DTOs generally have a `save()` method. You'd have to redesign how things work if your DTOs are immutable. DTOs are low-level: If the API of one isn't exactly to your liking, that's fine - make a second 'layer' API that uses DTOs to do its work. *That one* can be built around immutables.

Comment: Great points. Btw the casing convention is inconsistent: URISyntaxException, URLClassLoader.

Comment: @k314159 The types you mentioned predate the nuancing of the CamelCasing style rules. In fact, their existence caused issues which _then_ caused these style protocol updates. Java does not like to break backwards compatibility. You'll find that all recently introduced acronyms have proper casing. For example, it's `java.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute` but also `java.xml.XMLConstants`. XMLConstants is old, XmlAttribute is new. i.e. oracle agrees, as does every popular style guide in existence. Whatever's 'inconsistent' predates and is obsolete style.

Comment: I agree with most points. However, your definition of the DTO is wrong. It is not something that represents a row in a database and does not generally own a save method. What you are referring to seems to be an entity. DTO stands for 'Data Transfer Object' and can be used for a lot of things (mostly ser/des and mapping). Please read https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern.

Comment: It represents data transfer, it's the thing you transfer, you're somewhat handcuffed in how you design it as it is _designed_ to steer closely to the underlying data transfer model. But, sure, if that is itself in essence immutable, your DTO can (should!) be immutable too.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. Martin Fowler, in Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture, says: "Some people like to make Data Transfer Objects immutable. In this scheme you receive one Data Transfer Object from the client and create and send back a different one, even if it’s the same class. Other people alter the request Data Transfer Object. I don’t have any strong opinions either way, but on the whole I prefer a mutable Data Transfer Object because it’s easier to put the data in gradually, even if you make a new object for the response."

Comment: I've just looked at the joda-money library you linked to. It's been implemented using `BigDecimal`. After reading your thoughts here, I'm convinced it would have been better implemented using `long`.

Comment: I agree, and I generally recommend as rule of thumb to use `long` and not joda-money. But, if the complaint is specifically 'oof I want a more complicated class to represent this stuff because that fits my ideas of proper coding more regardless of the specifics of atomics', then using joda-money's got to be the better choice of writing BigDecimal yourself. My point is perhaps most of all: __If you use BigDecimal for money you are doing it wrong__ - because the correct answer is probably `long`, or possibly `joda-money`, either way, `BigDecimal` isn't the right answer.

Comment: ... and given that 'using double for money is wrong, use BigDecimal!' is extremely common advice on SO and elsewhere on the interwebs i have _a lot_ of preaching to do :)

Comment: I didn't mean it's better to use long than joda-money. I meant that joda-money itself is using BigDecimal instead of long.

Comment: Although most of the arguments here are good, it is actually irrelevant to the original question.  Simply "Price" does not necessary represent monetary amount (yes! It is totally possible.  For example you are working on Index Futures, the price is not a monetary amount) , and it is immature to assume OP does not take into account proper handling.  And, yes, simply sticking to BD is not whole solution BUT it is part of a proper solution.  That's the same even you adopt Joda-Money as per you suggested.

Comment: Just for discussion: even "Price" represent monetary amount, sometimes it does not necessarily align with atomicity of the ccy.  For example. In some market smallest spread is less than "smallest unit" of the ccy it is reported in, e.g. in Hong Kong, "atomicity" of HKD is 0.01 but there was stock price allowed up to 0.001 (or 0.005 ? I forgot).

So let's not divert the the focus of the question to something irrelevant.  (I do think the points you raised were valueable though  :) )

Comment: @AdriumShum on the contrary. The points made apply to anything 'price-like'. Specifically, OP __wants__ a limit on the decimals. That's pretty much the entire reason monetary amounts should be done as `long` and not `BD` - and therefore, it applies here regardless of what this mythical price-like limited-decimals concept is.

Comment: @AdriumShum and your second point is similarly irrelevant: Okay, on the HK stock market, the atomicity of _that_ was 0.1 of what was more general. Allright, so, just make your `long` represent those units. As long as there is an atomic unit of any sort, this advice applies. And just about every currency system has one, because it's far too difficult not to have one.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Honestly I couldn't agree on your point on how monetary amount should be handled, based on my 20+ year expereince on financial application development.  I have seen cases that use double/long/BigDecimal that were done correctly and also done wrong.  It is not using of long/BD etc that is solving the problem, it is about you need to understand how you should use them.  Using long is conceptually nothing different from using long, as they are both storing a integer value with a decimal scale when interpreting.  The whole reason why BD (or long) is preferred are simply

Comment: because traditional calculations are done in decimal, and the rules of calculation (e.g. when to take rounding, how many decimal to round to, what kind of rounding type you are using etc) are all done in decimal manner.  Adopting these "decimal-based" number representation form makes it much easier and more accurate to implement such calculation rules.   It is not whether it is long/BD that is solving the problem but whether such rules are properly implemented

Comment: @AdrianShum `BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2)` is not `.equals()` to `BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(3)`. That's just one of a billion reasons why saying: "I am very experienced; BigDecimal is just much easier" is ridiculous. Also, BD is not 'more accurate' than using `long` either. You say you have experience and then also say things that are easily objectively proven falsehoods. I think we're done here. Saying "just trust me, I am experienced" is not a logically sound argument in the first place.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I guess you didn't read my arguments right: 1. I have never said they are equals. Just the same as using long, if you have a value to represent value of "atomicity" of 2, vs another same value with atomicity of 4, they are not equals.  2. I am not saying BD is more "accurate", I said "more accurate in implement those calculation rules, as those rules are all based on decimal arithmetic".   I am not trying to convince only by my experience, but also giving reasoning behind.  Feel free to tell what I said is wrong (just as what I did to your points).

Comment: The reason I mentioned my experience was just to tell I have seen all these approaches, and have worked long enough to tell everyone that they could be all done correct and wrong.

Comment: Isn't this discussion a bit moot? Apart from the fact the BigDecimal can represent huge numbers (which is not a required feature here), I see BigDecimal and long as being virtually the same thing - they are fixed-point numbers. The main difference is the former has its scale stored in the same structure, while the latter has a scaled implied by the application.

Comment: Also, why do you think it's wrong that `BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2).equals(BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(3)) == false`? I see those two numbers as conceptually different types, as they have different scales, and therefore they must represent different things. The problem here is that the creators of Java have defined `equals` to allow checking different types, and to return false if they are different types. For example `aString.equals(aFile)` is `false`. Perhaps throwing an exception would have been better.

Comment: The `setScale()` vs `equals()` thing is an example of confusing and generally undesired behaviour. For BDs is fine: The semantic model of a BD is that it is a combination of price and scale, but as scale is more of a typal property (you really want a `List<BigDecimal{2}>` but that's not a thing java can do, having ints as type params), that's usually not a 'nice' property. For price specifically, it is __completely__ undesired. If you read `BigDecimal` and think `Price`, it's just flat out wrong that different scale but same amount nevertheless is considered not-equal.

Comment: If you fail to see how BD's `equals` behaviour in light of `scale` is confusing, we must come from different planets, that's.. that's the hill you're going to die on? Really? Walk a micrometer in the shoes of a new programmer and try to use your imagination, that's a _preposterous_ argument. And if you want to wave this one away as: Irrelevant - ALL BDs in the system will have scale of 2, so, it will never come up: No. `BigDecimal.ZERO` itself does not have that scale. Someone will use it. Things will break. This stuff won't happen with `long`. long has less 'mental load'.

Comment: @rzwitserloot you points actually shows you haven't been able to understand and use BD correctly.  1. In most system you do not want BigDecimal's scale statically defined as per you suggested, because the need to deal with different ccy.  2. Even for dealing with 1 ccy, in real life the intermediate calculation results are usually kept in higher scale, in order to reduce error caused by rounding.  3. ya, equals() may be a bit confusing but in real-life, people needs to know comparison of BD should be done with compare(), not equals().  4. I am not saying long is bad but, less mental load? cmon

Comment: tbh using long-based decimal number is my favourite approach too, but not because the problem you raised.  Actually the problem you raised mostly couldn't be solved just by switching to long-based-decimal, but require extra handling in calculation rule (e.g. the "split between 3" issue you mentioned).  I won't say BD is wrong in such a over-simplified manner. And, again, I simply feel this answer put too much hypothesis on what OP is trying to do, instead of just focusing the technical question he was trying to ask.  (I shouldn't complain though, as OP chose this as accepted answer  :P )

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a compact constructor and alter the input. Such constructor does not need to contain full constructor logic

```
public record WorldRecordDto(BigDecimal price, String name) {
    public WorldRecordDto {
        price = price.setScale(10);
        // you don't need to touch name
    }
}
...

BigDecimal p = new BigDecimal("10.123");
WorldRecordDto worldRecordDto = new WorldRecordDto(p, "Someone");
System.out.println("p: " + p.scale() + ", record: " + worldRecordDto.price.scale());  
// p: 3, record: 10
```